# why repo sync takes long time for some of the repos

Tags: git, repository

I am using below command to sync repos

```
repo sync -j5
```

however it takes long time to sync some of the repos or some of the tree.Suppose I am syncing tree `A` and when I switch to tree `B` and try `repo sync` there it takes more than double time to sync.
Can someone help me understand why is that and help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Try using following command, here -c make much lesser time

```
repo sync -c -j5
```

here `-c` is used as current branch defined in your manifest. so other data wont get fetched

Comment: Thanks. But you can even run "repo forall -c git gc" to clean up your tree. "git gc " will delete all unnecessary files. I have observed it takes 50% less time to sync tree.

Comment: Thanks for the '-c' recommendation. I don't see it in the Android docs: https://source.android.com/source/using-repo#sync Is there any other place to read about it?